# Formatting Date in Query results

Tags: sql-server, date

I am trying to get results from a query in a specific format and I cant seem to find an answer for it.

This is my code:

```
SELECT convert(date, TimeReported, 101) as 'Error Date', count(ErrorDetails) as 'Error Count' 

FROM ErrorLog

where ErrorDetails like '%login failed%' 

GROUP BY Convert(date, TimeReported, 101) 

order by 'Error Date' desc
```

I want the date results to be displayed like mm/dd/yyyy

```
Error Date  Error Count:
11/12/2015  1
11/05/2015  3
03/24/2015  4
```

The code above gives my results: yyyy/mm/dd

```
Error Date  Error Count
2015-11-12  1
2015-11-05  3
2015-03-24  4
```

Comment: I don't know the consumer of your data, but I would highly suggest you allow the consumer to format it at the time it needs to be formatted, and not at the database level.

Comment: Yup, formatting on the back end is pretty counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ;with cte as
(
SELECT convert(varchar(10), TimeReported, 101) as 'Error Date', count(ErrorDetails) as 'Error Count' 
FROM ErrorLog
where ErrorDetails like '%login failed%' 
GROUP BY convert(varchar(10), TimeReported, 101) 
)

select * 
from cte
order by YEAR(CONVERT(date,[Error Date])) desc,  [Error Count] asc
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: That gets me the format results but then with the order by statement it uses the month to order by not the year

Comment: Sorry, just change the order by to be the TimeReported column , and not the alias "error date".  Updated answer.

Comment: That gives me: Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Column "ErrorLog.TimeReported" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your query:

```
convert(nvarchar(10), TimeReported, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2012 or newer, you have a much richer way of formatting data, including dates.  Use the new `Format` function.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx

With this function you can use any .NET format specifier, either single letter versions (Standard) or Custom formatters. So, instead of 
`convert(date, TimeReported, 101) as 'Error Date'`, you can use `format(date, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as 'Error Date'`. And yes, it is case sensitive. If you used "mm" instead of "MM", you would get minutes instead.